# Сортировка строк содержащих цифры

Tags: java, алгоритм, ormlite

Считываются имена с таблицы базы данных MySQL.

Выводятся в таком порядке:

```
А.1  А.10  А.11 А.2  А.3
```

Как реализовать правильную сортировку?

Средства MySQL не предлагать, так как использую ORMLite.

Comment: А не имеет значения это средства MySQL или чего либо еще. в любом случае вам надо выделить цифры и дополнить их нулями до одинаковой длины слева, после чего отсортировать как строку. Либо отсортировать по нецифровому началу, а внутри одинаковых начал отсортировать числовыми методами по выделенному числу

Comment: Реализовать свой `Comparator`, который отсортирует так, как вам нужно. Если вы хотите не лексикографическую сортировку, которая показана в примере, вам придется парсить строки, вычленять из них число и использовать это в компараторе.

Answer (score 2):

Должно быть, что то такое:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("А.1", "А.10", "А.11", "А.2", "А.3");

    stringList
            .stream()
            .sorted(
                    (e1, e2) -> {
                        String[] s1 = e1.split("\\.");
                        String[] s2 = e2.split("\\.");

                        int result = s1[0].compareTo(s2[0]);
                        if (result != 0) return result;

                        return Integer.valueOf(s1[1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2[1]));
                    }
            ).forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

```
А.1
А.2
А.3
А.10
А.11
```

Comment: А как быть в случае если данная строка является полем объекта?

Comment: Всм? У вас строки типа "object.field"?  тогда что это за объект и какого типа?

Comment: В вашем примере был список строк. А у меня список объектов, определенного типа, у каждого есть несколько полей, оди из них строка, все строки и надо отсортировать, т.е. объекты по строкам

Comment: Тогда измените компаратор, и сравниваете те поля на основе которых определяется порядок.

Answer (score 1):

С сортировкой строк можно использовать небольшую хитрость с hashCode.

```
return Stream.of("А.1", "А.10", "А.11", "А.2", "А.3")
            .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.hashCode(), b.hashCode()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: А можно пояснить?

Comment: @Qwertiy hash code для string считается следующим образом : h = 31 * h + val[i];   видимо для строк с одинаковым префиксом он будет различаться лишь разностью между суммой последний символов (unicode код) умноженных на 31. Но тут стоит учитывать что возможно переполнение и прочие радости. Красивое решение, но в общем случае будет работать не правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вот компаратор:

- Разбиваем строку на "чанки" цифровые и нет
- Сравниваем поэтапно, по кусочкам

Код класса:

```
public class AlphaNumericComparator implements Comparator {
    private final boolean isDigit(char ch) {return ch >= 48 && ch <= 57; }

    private final String getChunk(String s, int len, int p) {
        StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();
        char c = s.charAt(p);
        chunk.append(c);
        p++;
        bool isDigitC = isDigit(c);
        while (p < len) {
            c = s.charAt(p);
            if (isDigitC != isDigit(c)) break;
            chunk.append(c);
            p++;
        }
        return chunk.toString();
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (!(o1 instanceof String) || !(o2 instanceof String)) return 0;
        String s1 = (String)o1, s2 = (String)o2;
        int p1 = 0, p2 = 0;
        int len1 = s1.length(), len2 = s2.length();

        while (p1 < len1 && p2 < len2) {
            String chunk1 = getChunk(s1, len1, p1);
            String chunk2 = getChunk(s2, len2, p2);
            p1 += chunk1.length();
            p2 += chunk2.length();

            int result = 0;
            // Оба куска числа - сравниваем как числа
            if (isDigit(chunk1.charAt(0)) && isDigit(chunk2.charAt(0))) {
                result = chunk1.length() - chunk2.length(); // сравниваем по длине
                if (result == 0) result = chunk1.compareTo(chunk2); // Длины совпадают, сравниваем, как строки
            } else {
                result = chunk1.compareTo(chunk2);
            }

            if (result != 0) return result;
        }

        return len1 - len2;
    }
}
```